# Opera SDK development

Tags: javascript, html, css, sdk, opera

In AlistAPart article, I've found a mention about [this Opera Widgets SDK](http://dev.opera.com/sdk/). Does anyone have some experience with It? The description says:

> Opera Widgets are self-contained Web applications built using open Web standards such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Widgets are cross-platform and cross-device, meaning you can deploy them anywhere, from desktop to mobile to TV, and more besides.

What advantage It offer compared to other HTML/CSS/Javascript technologies for cross-browser development?

Comment: It's not for cross browser development, it's for 'out of browser' development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera widgets are standalone "apps" made with front-end web technologies, which use Opera's engine(s) to render the app/content. Think Dashboard widgets on OS X, or those Windows desktop widgets. But also all those AIR/Flex apps. And apps for phones etc.

The cool thing about Opera Widgets is that Opera is trying to make their widgets conform to the W3C Widgets spec. That's probably what sets it apart from other widget toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

It's very much analogous to Dashboard widgets on OS X, gadgets on Vista/Win7, etc., built upon web standards to create small standalone apps. Opera's widget model is nowadays based upon the ongoing W3C work on widgets, which is seeing uptake in a variety of places.